# Persist JSON Data - Appcelarator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm using the Titanium framework and Alloy plugin, and I need to consume a REST api in my application, I would like to know if there is a good way to consume this api and persist JSON she returns at a local bank.

Comment: Look at `Ti.App.Properties`

Comment: I think this will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple Alloy REST adapters and examples for you to start working with, here are a few links

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Alloy+Sync+Adapters+and+Migrations

https://medium.com/all-titanium/enhancing-titanium-simplify-your-api-interactions-with-reste-collections-15063468456b

https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi

Comment: Thanks, the second link helped me with what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SculeJS](https://github.com/dan-eyles/sculejs/) as a NoSQL database ;-)

It can store the data in the same structure that you receive it from the REST service. On top of that it does geo calculations (which I need).

/John